# Selecting data from two different tables

Tags: sql, select, count

I'm using SQL and need to select the idR and a count of how many ingredients are in that idR.

How would I go about doing this?

- Recipe = (`idR, recipeTitle, prepText, cuisineType, mealType`)
- Ingredient = (`idI, ingrDesc`)
- RecipIngr = (`idR*, idI*`)

This is what I've tried

```
SELECT 
    RECIPE.idR
FROM 
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM INGREDIENT 
     GROUP BY INGREDIENT.idI
     ORDER BY idI.id DESC)
```

but I'm just wanting a count of how many ingredients are in each idR.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your schema,

```
SELECT idR, count(*)
FROM RecipIngr
GROUP BY idR
```

Answer (score 0):

use only the association table if you are only interested on the `IDR`

```
SELECT  iDR, COUNT(*) totalIngredients
FROM    RecipIngr
GROUP   BY iDR
```

but if you want to get the `TITLE`

```
SELECT  a.iDR, a.Title,
        COUNT(*) totalIngredients
FROM    Recipe a
        INNER JOIN RecipIngr b
            ON a.idr = b.idr
GROUP   BY a.iDR, a.Title
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RG.IDR, COUNT(RG.IDR)
FROM Recipingr RG
GROUP BY RG.IDR
```

Answer (score 0):

RecipIngr is the one that shows you the list of ingredients you need for each idR?   the code would be

```
SELECT idR, count(*)
FROM RecipIngr
GROUP BY idR
```

EDIT: I misunderstood earlier but this should work now

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your query, you could try this:

```
select recipe.idr, count(ingredient.idi)
from ingredient, recipe, recipingr
where ingredient.idr=recipingr.idr
and recipingr.idi=ingredient.idi
group by recipe.idr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,INGREDIENT.INGREDIENT_Count 
FROM RECIPE INNER JOIN (SELECT idR,COUNT(*) INGREDIENT_Count  
                        FROM RecipIngr 
                        GROUP BY idR) INGREDIENT ON INGREDIENT.idR RECIPE.idR
```

Using this Query you can get Ingredient Count for each Recipe.